# Javascript Angular Insert variable in data-target as id

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular4 and I have some data value that I want to insert dynamically as an id in data-target.

What I do this is works fine:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myid">Edit</a>
```

But when I do this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{item.id}}">Edit</a>
```

For some reason the line above is converting to this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" target="#{{item.id}}">Edit</a>
```

So, no longer data target by turns to target.

Why? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Try `data-target="{{'#' + item.id}}"`

Comment: Same problem...the "data-" gets scrapped out. I've never seen this before :o/

Comment: Try `attr.data-target='{{"#" + item.id}}'`. [Here's a plunker showing](http://embed.plnkr.co/haH7wk1GgJyAFaOPotvt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use angular attr binding instead of interpolation:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#' + item.id">Edit</a>
```